# grails access controller from taglib

Tags: grails, groovy

Is it possible to access the current controller instance from within a TagLib? For example:

```
class FooTagLib {
    static namespace = 'foo'

    def msg = { attrs, body ->          
      // Can I get a reference to the current controller here?
    }
}
```

I want to do this because I store some data in a property of the controller and want to access it within the TagLib. I realise this may sound strange, but just humour me....

Answer (score 5):

Inside your msg tagLib:

```
grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName('Controller', pageScope.controllerName)
```

Like Views, you have access to the current controller and action through `controllerName` and `actionName`

Comment: Fabien, why use `pageScope.controllerName` instead of just `controllerName`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
def ctl = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName('Controller', 'whateverController')
```

Comment: I can't hard-code the name of the controller (whateverController) because I've no way of knowing which controller handled the current request

Comment: Ah, then you've stumped me.  Sorry.

Comment: Could you possibly pass them in as params to the taglib?  I believe you can access it via params.controller.  Just make sure you taglib requires the controller instance passed to it.