# Wrapping A Groovy Tag Around A Custom Tag

Tags: grails

Essentially, I'm trying to find a DRYer way to represent this code:

```
<li><g:link controller="ActivityDashboard" action="summary">Summary</g:link></li>
<li><g:link controller="ActivityDashboard" action="user_details">User Details</g:link></li>
<li><g:link controller="ActivityDashboard" action="groups_monitors">Groups & Monitors</g:link></li>
<li><g:link controller="ActivityDashboard" action="Top Content">Top Content</g:link></li>
<li><g:link controller="ActivityDashboard" action="embedded_components">Embedded Components</g:link></li>
<li><g:link controller="ActivityDashboard" action="customer_summary">Customer Summary</g:link></li>
```

As you can see, there is a lot of repetition so I created the a tag as the following:

```
def navLink = { attrs, body ->
  out << "<li>"
  out << "<g:link controller='ActivityDashboard' action='${attrs.action}'>${attrs.title}"
  out << "</g:link></li>"
}
```

However, the output html is exactly:

```
<g:link action="summary" controller="ActivityDashboard">Summary</g:link>
```

How can I get to render like:

```
<a href="/engagementlevels/activityDashboard/summary">Summary</a>
```

Bonus Points: Can I access the the actionName attribute of the page from a tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the g.link() version of the tag so that the GString parses it and renders the output like you want.

```
out << g.link(attrs.title, controller: 'ActivityDashboard', action: attrs.action)
```

Comment: You had the right idea but I think your answer can be improved. Check my edit.

Comment: Greg, you answered this question here that would answer my bonus question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462552/grails-access-controller-from-taglib , how do I get the actionName in a tag?